# Steering wheel vibration after changing mounts on a 2002 Ford F150 4.2L V6

Tags: ford, f-150, motor-mounts

I changed the transmission and engine mounts on the truck now I have a vibration in the steering wheel and can feel it in park and driving.

Comment: Did you use all new mounts or are they used ones?

Comment: Did you use poly mounts or stock rubber mounts?

Answer (score 2):

I would perform the same test to check for bad engine mounts, in the first place.

Place your foot on the brake, engine in gear, and give it a bit of gas. Through the gap under the [raised] hood, watch the engine to see if it jumps up > 1 inch. If it is jumping, have someone watch the engine closer (or swap positions with you) to see if you can identify the point of movement. Perhaps a mount isn't fully secured.

On the other hand, Ebay sells some extremely cheap, low quality "new" mounts, I don't doubt that some could feel even worse than well-worn OEM mounts.

Safety first, stand to the side, not in front of the vehicle when doing this.